THTTPRIO no firing OnNeedClientCertificate event
I try to use a certificate from the certificate store on Windows for za SOAP service, but it always ask for a certificate with a displayed dialog.
My code:
  ...
  var RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  RIO.HTTPWebNode.HTTP.OnNeedClientCertificate := DoOnClientCertificateNeeded;
  RIO.HTTPWebNode.GetHTTPReqResp.PreemptiveAuthentication := true;

  var svc := wsETurizemPorocanje.GetrnoSoap(false, '', RIO);

  data := TXmlData.Create;
  data.LoadFromXml(xml.XML);
  var errors := svc.oddajPorocilo('UserName', 'Password', data , 1);
  ...
end;

procedure TeTurizem.DoOnClientCertificateNeeded(const Sender: TObject; const ARequest: TURLRequest; const ACertificateList: TCertificateList; var AnIndex: Integer);
begin
  for var idx := 0 to ACertificateList.Count - 1 do begin
    if ACertificateList[idx].SerialNum = AppSettings.Server.Hostel.ETurizemSettings.CertSerial then begin
      if (ACertificateList[idx].Start<=Now) and (ACertificateList[idx].Expiry>Now) then begin
         AnIndex := idx;
         break;
      end else
        raise Exception.Create('(DoOnClientCertificateNeeded) Client Certificate Expired.');
    end;
  end;
end;

I'm going nuts, because I can't find a lot of documentation or examples.
What do I need to provide the SOAP call a certificate from the cert store? Isn't defining the event enough?

This is because when you call the httprio code, it overwrites your eventhandler. Check the procedure THTTPReqResp.SetupHttp(Http: THttpClient); in the Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans unit.   "FHTTP.OnNeedClientCertificate := DoNeedClientCertificate";
I would almost say this is a bug.

You need to define an event handler with the following signature:
procedure MyDoNeedClientCertificate(const Sender: TObject;
  const ARequest: TURLRequest; const ACertificateList: TCertificateList;
  var AnIndex: Integer);

procedure TForm1.MyDoNeedClientCertificate(const Sender: TObject; const ARequest: TURLRequest; const ACertificateList: TCertificateList;
  var AnIndex: Integer);
begin
  for var I := 0 to ACertificateList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if ACertificateList[I].CertName.Contains(edCertName.Text) then
    begin
      if ACertificateList[I].Expiry > now then
      begin
        AnIndex := I;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

Then bind that in the HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost event:
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Client: THTTPClient);
begin
  HTTPReqResp.OnNeedClientCertificate := MyDoNeedClientCertificate;
end;

This way you bind the eventhandler after it gets overwritten in the SetupHttp procedure.

The procedure is now hit, but there is a new problem - the site returns the error "Forbidden (403) - 'https://wwwt.ajpes.si/rno/rnoApi/eTurizem/wsETurizemPorocanje.asmx''.". If I remove the event, then I got asked for the certificate and the server method is executed correctly.

Both this method and the one where you choose the certificate set AIndex. Jump into the delphi code to see which AIndex works and why it gives a different one here that doesn't work.

Thanks for the tip - the error was in fact there. I changed "CertName" to "SerialNum" and it worked! Thanks a lot to everyone!
